# Visual Studio 2013. Can panes update while I am moving splitters?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I want to panes will update while I am moving splitter in VS2012 and VS2013. I didn't find such option. Can I do this?

Comment: Specify more: what UI framework do you use? Or are you talking about VS's own UI itself?

Comment: VS's own UI itself. And i am talking about vs editor not about software developed by VS.

Comment: I'm sure you talking about the use-case when you split the area by two (or more) different files. However when you use the special splitter on the top right corner which splits the same file horizontally (you'll be able to see different sections of the same file), that updates.

Comment: I didn't see any relevant settings in VS 2012's Tools > Options... > Environment > Tabs and Windows, or in Editors or such.